# Definition of Entity Framework context Base Options

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am seeing base(options) in Entity Framework examples. What does base(options) mean, since cannot locate Microsoft documentation.

```
public class BloggingContext : DbContext
{
      public BloggingContext(DbContextOptions<BloggingContext> options)
          : base(options)
      { }


}
```

Example here:
Documentation does define DbContextOptions, but not base options.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext

Comment: by using `:base(options)` you are providing `DbContextOptions` parameter `options` to base class constructor and I think here `DbContext` is base class.

Comment: thanks, feel free to write as answer, I can give points

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is related to one of the basic principles of `OOP`, `Inheritance`. Whenever you are creating an instance of the derived class, you will see that base class constructor will be called first.

In this case, whenever an instance of `BloggingContext` is being created, `DbContext` class constructor is also being called first and it is `parameter-less` default constructor (if you don't use `:base(soemthing)`). If you see the definition of `DbContext` class then you will see that there is two constructors, one is parameter-less and other is taking `DbContextOptions options` as parameter.

So when you are creating an instance of derived class, you can make the decision which appropriate constructor for the base class should be called and in this case you are calling the second constructor by passing constructor parameter value as follows:

```
public BloggingContext(DbContextOptions<BloggingContext> options)
    : base(options)
{ }
```

That's it!